crypto.com check user balance
Not sure if im being a bit silly with this or if the API just doesnt work.
I am using crypto.com exchange API to trade crypto and it works fine for buying and selling. But when I use the endpoint to check user balances if just get a response of BAD_REQUEST
My code is below:
<?php
require_once 'crypto_api.php';

// Function to fetch balances from Crypto.com API
function fetch_balances() {
    global $api_key, $api_secret;

    $nonce = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
    $method = 'private/get-account-summary';
    $id = $nonce;
    $params = []; // No additional parameters needed for this call

    // Generate signature
    $sig = generate_signature($method, $id, $api_key, $params, $nonce, $api_secret);

    $request_params = [
        'id' => $id,
        'method' => $method,
        'api_key' => $api_key,
        'nonce' => $nonce,
        'params' => $params,
        'sig' => $sig
    ];

    $payload = json_encode($request_params);

    // Make API call
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.crypto.com/v2/private/get-account-summary');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($http_code != 200) {
        echo "HTTP Error: $http_code\nResponse: $response\n";
        return null;
    }

    $result = json_decode($response, true);

    if (isset($result['error'])) {
        echo "API Error: " . $result['error']['message'] . "\n";
        return null;
    }

    return $result['result']['accounts'] ?? [];
}

// Display balances in a readable format
function display_balances() {
    $balances = fetch_balances();

    if (!$balances) {
        echo "Failed to fetch balances or no balances available.\n";
        return;
    }

    echo "Your Current Balances:\n";
    echo "----------------------\n";

    foreach ($balances as $balance) {
        $currency = $balance['currency'];
        $available = $balance['available'];
        $reserved = $balance['reserved'];

        echo "Currency: $currency\n";
        echo "Available: $available\n";
        echo "Reserved: $reserved\n";
        echo "----------------------\n";
    }
}

// Run the balance retrieval
display_balances();
?>

I've even filtered this through AI to help with a resolution and still no dice. Absolutely no idea what I could be missing here and any help would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT: I have edited to include the error message exactly as I receive it:

HTTP Error: 400 Response: {"code":"10004","msg":"BAD_REQUEST"}


https://static2.crypto.com/exchange/assets/documents/Crypto.com%20Exchange%20Spot%20v2.1%20to%20Exchange%20v1%20API%20Migration%20Guide.pdf

The message is clear, get-account-summary does not seem to exist - according to the documentation.

Thank you, I have been through this documentation already but didnt really help me resolve whatever is wrong. Ive looked at the granular code types too.

Ah I had that end point in my code above because I seen an old thread where it worked for them. But any enpoint I use for balances and order history all result in a bad request response.

The "Bad request" response is telling you that either the endpoint name, or some parameter in the request, is not valid. You need to check each item against the official documentation to try and discover why.

Thanks for the reply. Ye but I really dont see the issue. The payload im sending is:
Payload Sent: {"id":1734274738421,"method":"private\/get-account-summary","api_key":"<removed>","nonce":1734274738421,"params":{},"sig":"095a8d3cee74e220000cc7989aa09f1e28d299b96931f49b149ea99a20c1ab33"}
I know the sig generation works because its working for other endpoints. For example, this payload private/get-account-summary endpoint. Finding it really confusing because I know someone else who cant seem to get it working either

Are you sure you're supposed to use the same value for id and nonce? The examples in the documentation linked by @gre_gor suggest these should be different values?
